# PowerMokito issue with extended methods

Tags: powermock

**Issue:** Cannot stub a method on a return object from an extended class.I just get null pointers on the method I am trying to stub. Do I need to perform a spy first on the objects? I tried that as well and didn't work.

Test Framework:
PowerMockito version 1.9
PowerMock version 1.4.11
EasyMock version 3.1

**Line of code attempting to test.**

`String expected = methodFromExtendedClass_GetObject().getStringValueFromReturnObject();`

**Test Code**

`PowerMockito.stub(MemberModifier.method(ExtendedClassA.class, "methodFromExtendedClass_GetObject()")).toReturn(new testObject());`

`PowerMockito.stub(MemberModifier.method(testObject.class, "getStringValueFromReturnObject")).toReturn(testString);`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the EasyMock syntax, but I do know Mockito. I dont have too much to work with here, but it seems that you are just trying to create a Stubbed Object to return another Mock that returns a string.

If so, Create the Mock test object:

```
TestObject testObject = mock(TestObject.class);

when(testObject.getStringValueFromReturnObject()).thenReturn(testString);
```

Then use that Mock as the return for your stub:

```
PowerMockito.stub(MemberModifier.method(ExtendedClassA.class, 
           "methodFromExtendedClass_GetObject()")).toReturn(testObject);
```